# How to add a specific line on top of each page (Mediawiki)

Tags: php, mediawiki

i wanted to add the VoteNY extension to my wiki, so all users can rate each other. This extensions needs the line

```
<vote type="1"></vote>
```

on each page that should be voteable.
Now i am trying to **initially** write these line on top of each page (~10000 pages) programmatically. i already found a hook to add the line when a new article is created. But every page should be have this line.

This is what i have so far:

```
<?php
$TitleList = [];    
# get the edit ticket
$jsn = file_get_contents('http://wiki/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json');
$json_a = json_decode($jsn, true);
$token = $json_a['query']['tokens']['csrftoken'];

# populate the list of all pages
$urlGET = 'http://wiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json';
$json = file_get_contents($urlGET);
$json_b = json_decode( $json ,true);
foreach  ($json_b['query']['allpages'] as $page)
{
    array_push($TitleList, $page['title']);
}

# //add the line on top of every page
foreach ($TitleList as $title)
{
    $data = array(
        'action'      => 'edit',
        'title'       => $title,
        'prependtext' => '<vote type="1"></vote>',
        'token'       => $token);
    # Create a connection
    $url = 'http://wiki/api.php?';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    # Form data string, automatically urlencode
    $postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
    # Setting our options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    # Get the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);            
    echo($response);    
}
```

This is functionable so far. But i recognized that `&list=allpages` didn't give me all pages (40% are missing) of my wiki.

Comment: Do you have a lot of edits on your wiki (multiple edits per minutes)? Or would you be satisfied with just going through all pages once, adding the line, and ignoring pages that have been created/moved/edited while your script ran?

Comment: i'll be satisfied with just going through all pages, ignoring new/edited pages.

Comment: Then I'd simply use [`action=query&list=allpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages]) to fetch all pages in the namespace you are interested in, and then the `prependtext` options in [`action=edit`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit) to add your code snippet

Comment: It sounds like the extension does not quite do what you want. Modifying it (e.g. splitting VoteHooks::renderVote into a part that needs the parser and a part that doesn't, so that the second one can be invoked from some generic hook on every page) is probably a better option.

Comment: thanks for the tip @leo. i edited my progress into the question

Comment: You need to add `&format=json` to the API call, you are currently fetching a human readable version of the output. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json and https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So thanks to the hints and tips in the comments. I managed to get the script running correct. i edited into my Question.

Comment: You might want to create a new question for this, as this answer will probably me deleted for not being an answer.

Comment: ...and now that the question is edited out, it's more of a comment, than an answer :D
If you want to answer your own question, try to state the question clearly above, and the solution here. The idea here is to make the Q&A's as useful as possible to others, and since most users won't be watching the whole edit history of your question, they won't be able to get much guidance